# Opening a csv file in another app from flutter shows it has corrupt

Tags: flutter, csv, flutter-dependencies, export-to-csv

I want to export a CSV file from my app. I implemented the following simplified code:

```dart
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:open_file_plus/open_file_plus.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


    // Get directory where a file can be saved
      Directory? _externalDocumentsDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Example
    String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert([
      ['header_1', 'header_2'],
      ['value_1', 'value_2']
    ]);

    // Write csv
    File f = File("${_externalDocumentsDirectory!.path}/filename.csv");
    f.writeAsString(csv);

    // Open it
    await OpenFile.open(f.path);
```

This works as expected in the sense that it saves the file at the desired location, and if you use another app like `google sheets` to open that file it works.

But the last piece `OpenFile.open(f.path);` does not seem to work as I expect. It lunches the menu to select with which app you want to open it. But `google sheets`, `xiaomi mi spreadsheets` or `reader mi browser` show it is corrupt.

If I print the result of opening it just shows the message `done`.

If I add the paramters `type: '.csv'` it shws `No APP found to open this file`

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I came across [this discussion](https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/issues/155):

In the original plugin where the plugin I'm working was found.

After providing the type as follows it is now working:

```dart
await OpenFile.open(
  f.path,
  type: 'text/csv',
  uti: 'public.comma-separated-values-text',
);
```